# Clearing TEMP files on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I'm sure that my Mac is filled with crap by now, being 2 years old. Is there an app that will clear the temp files away? Or is there a list of locations filled with TEMP stuff I can safely delete without killing my Mac?

Comment: OSX does quite a good job in removing temporary files automatically. Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: Nope just in general

Comment: Give Onyx a try: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the [Beta of CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/mac/ccleaner), and it cleared out 10 GB of stuff, 7GB from the Trash. It's free and worked great

Answer (score 1):

Y u no use OnyX? Free and really popular with really quick updates for every edition of OS X. It has a great feature set and works great for fixing corrupted temp files/caches

Comment: Cause I didn't see it before trying CCleaner. I hate that about the SE inbox

Comment: What is the reason you're looking to delete temp files? 99% of the time deleting them just because they "seem" unnecessary will slow your system down until they're rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested to try [CleanMyMac](http://macpaw.com/).
Features:

1. Cache cleaner
2. Logs cleaner
3. Universal binaries cleaner
4. System junk cleaner
5. Language cleaner
6. Trash and leftovers
7. Application uninstaller
8. ...

Comment: You're joking right? Those guys? The guys that sell their program for $14.99 but only provide a 6 month licence? The same guys that give free copies to people in exchange they post top ratings on places like http://www.macupdate.com/? Those smarmy SOBs? Really? You want to line their pockets and recommend their junk? I wouldn't use their stuff (even if it was good and didn't hose application updates with their daemon) on sheer principle!

Comment: maybe you are right, but I didn't know any equivalent to this software!